# Heroku reduce memory consumption for TensorFlow app

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

I have a TensorFlow model in flask app on Heroku with a POST request to access the predictor of the model. However, it seems that I am exceeding the memory of my deployed Heroku instance:

```
2020-10-09T12:32:39.186188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=792M(138.9%)
2020-10-09T12:32:39.188901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I suspect much of this has to do with TensorFlow 2.0 taking up a lot of memory. I tried using TensorFlow 1.0, but my code wouldn't run since I'm using a specific TensorFlow Hub model.

I know I can purchase a bigger plan, but the only plan I see that has a memory upgrade is a $50 per month one.

Are there are any ways to reduce this memory? For example, is it possible to shift the pip packages data to the disk and only keep the RAM for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge with TensorFlow (and any other framework loading pretrained or statistical models) is that they need to load the predictive model in memory.
One option is to use a smaller model (if possible) sacrificing accuracy.

Other options are indeed to purchase a bigger plan or change provider (I solved memory issues when moving to DigitalOcean - for some reasons Heroku used a lot more memory when running my Docker image. DigitalOcean is not free but for 5$ a month you can get a good performing Droplet)

Comment: Do you have experience at AWS services such as EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk? Based on my estimate, that could be just $1 per month

Comment: Not much, I have used AWS for a data engineering course. It works fine and it seems to be one of the cheapest option for small usage (ideal for learning and prototyping)